# Is it possible to run OpenZFS on MacOS Sierra on a Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac-pro, raid, zfs

I have a Mac Pro with a PCIe flash startup drive running MacOS Sierra. I would like to fill the 4 empty SATA HDD bays with drives and use OpenZFS to create a pool/volume.

1. Is this configuration possible?
2. What risks/issues might I face with this setup? For example, how might macOS updates affect accessing my ZFS data pool?

I'm open to using MacOS Sierra's RAID tools, but I prefer to use the ZFS file system for this due to its superior data protection and compression features.

Comment: Take a look at [this site](https://www.akitio.com/software/akitio-raidz-manager) for some info on doing OpenZFS RAID on macOS.

Comment: Thanks @bret7600, does the software only work if the drives are mounted in an Akitio external enclosure?

Comment: So sorry, I overlooked something in the release notes... am so used to just using it... Take a look at [this command line tool](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?zpool(8)). -- sorry again.

Comment: I think that you may be able to use the reference [here](https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Zpool#Creating_a_pool) for Zpool on the [OpenZFS wiki](https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the links from other users, it seems that it is possible to create a ZFS RAID in the configuration I am looking for.

However for me, the OpenZFS system is not yet mature enough to be my solution on macOS Sierra for these reasons:

1. Cannot backup ZFS volume using Time Machine
2. The Photos application, which is dependent on HFS, only "sometimes" works.

See the Interoperability and Limitations section here:

https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/FAQ

Comment: i believe time machine support is now supported by zfs using sparse bundle images, for those coming here from search engines

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is: I am using zfs, including after upgrading to High Sierra and after updating zfs a few times.

After updating macOS I vaguely recall reinstalling zfs for this version of macOS (and possibly uninstalling it first--fairly certain I followed the directions associated with the installer or in the wiki), and then later as zfs was updated installed the newer release. I was prompted to upgrade the zpool in the normal course of using my external drive (when I did `sudo zpool import -a -f`).